Manga/manhua/manhwa where the heroine has silver/white hair
She is engaged to a prince, but is forced to break it off by her stepmother in favor of her own daughter after being starved in a locked room. She is sent to a....fiefdom but is ultimately executed for mistreatment of funds(framed). She returned to the past, with the knowledge of some events. She breaks off the engagement herself this time but her stepmother still seems to want her dead. She volunteers to go to the fiefdom and actually makes it better over the course of a few years. But the queen summons her back. She is a more appealing candidate to the queen. But her stepsister still thinks she should be queen and tries to sabotage the tests the queen makes, because the king, the queen's son, likes her.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I read this like a year ago, let it marinate, then lost my old phone, soooo I didn't remember it

There are several manga sites you can read it for free

This is I Refuse to be Executed a Second Time. It is licensed by Pocket Comics

Ella Walker looks back on her life atop a guillotine. She was forced to cancel her engagement with Prince Gil in favor of her stepsister Isabella and demoted to rule a desolate hinterland. Then, the resulting riot leads to Ella getting executed. But after the execution, she somehow ends up reincarnated ten years into the past. Having been given a chance to do it all over again, Ella is determined to live her new life freely, without being tied down. She gives up her spot as Prince Gil's fiancee to Isabella and decides to work hard to reform the hinterland as its new lord.

The synopsis is a perfect match for the question.
In chapter 1 she is asked to voluntarily give up her position as the prince's fiance in favor of her step sister. She does not, and is sent to an attic with a vague excuse.

She is sent off to the hinterlands, a ruined land, and is accused of ruining it and is executed at the start of the story. She wakes up years in the past and decides to move there voluntarily.
